# Disable completion pop-up in python-mode shadowing indentation

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, indentation, python-mode

I updated recently my version of python-mode.el. Since then pressing  at end of lines tries completion instead of indentation and pops up a buffer of suggestion.
I would rather have only indentation. I use something else for completion.
How can this be achieved?

By the way, auto indentation grew /less/ smart with the update. What possibly have I broken?

Comment: I tried f1 k but did not find out what to do. Feel free to add support to your comment if you have something particular in mind.

Comment: `f1 k TAB` should definitely help, since it will tell you the command name that is being executed
and the map in which it is defined. So far, I don't even know if it's `auto-complete` or `company-mode` or whatever.
`f1 k` *always* works.

Comment: In this case it is a little more intricate because several modules use tab (at least yasnippet, auto-complete, python-mode). I am looking for what changed in version 6 of python mode compared to version 5 that cause the overall behaviour to changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell which python-mode. Also assume it's about TAB-key.

WRT python-mode.el comment out the present key-setting and write the desired one.

Like that:

```
;; (define-key map (kbd "TAB") 'py-indent-or-complete)
(define-key map (kbd "TAB") 'py-indent-line)
```

Comment: I was reluctant to edit the mode file if some option were present but I must admit this is simple and efficient. Thanks.

Comment: @AlfredM. Glad being helpful. In related cases people may consider to file a feature request at https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to modify the mode file itself to make this happen.  You should be able to do it via `python-mode-hook`.  This works for me (in my `~/.emacs`):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'py-indent-line))
```